# Full emulation esme

Tags: java, linux, sms, smpp

I want to know if it is possible to emulate work: Mobile Phone (sms, ussd) -> SMSC -> ESME on linux (preferably written in java) ? Sorry for my English...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SMPPSim SMSC simulator](http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/downloads.html) to check if ESME works correctly.

For ESME you can use [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org) - you can define some simple services there without extra programming.